# Get metadata from list_objects_v2 boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I try to get user defined metadata by using boto3 paginator `list_objects_v2`

```
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=user_folder_name)

for page in pages:
    contents = page.get('Contents')
    if contents is None:
        if page.get('KeyCount') == 0:
            continue
        else:
            raise Exception(str(page))

    for obj in contents:
        # Ok
        key = obj['Key']
        
        # Ok
        etag = obj.get('ETag')
            
        # Not Ok
        metadata = obj.get('Metadata')
        if metadata is not None:
            print("DEBUG -> " + json.dumps(metadata), flush=True)
        else:
            print("No meta data " + str(page), flush=True)
```

But, after inspecting the respond, I do not find user defined metadata in the `list_objects_v2` respond.

Does anyone know how to retrieve list of metadata for a list of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) API call does *not* return Metadata.

You would need to call [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) or [`get_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) on *each* object individually to obtain their Metadata.